# How can I create an order form?

Tags: android, list, forms

I am new to Android, and am trying to develop an app that presents a list of choices with a textfield next to each that allows the user to enter in quantity information related to each item.

What would be the best way to impliment this?  Currently my app is using a buttonlist with checkboxes next to each item to select it.  I'd like to expand this so that I can select multiples of the same item.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a `Spinner` for the item and an `EditText` for the quantity.